# A6 gsm/gprs module TCP/IP connection to Cloud

Tags: sockets, tcp, gsm, gprs, m2m

I want to send data with **A6 GSM/GPRS** module to ***data.sparkfun.com*** cloud service. I am using these AT commands:

```
// Setting up network 

AT+CGATT?
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
AT+CGACT=1,1
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIFSR

// Start the TCP/IP connection to the server

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","54.86.132.254",80    // PROBLEM STARTS HERE       
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPSEND
GET /input/***********?private_key=****************&temp=45.2 HTTP/1.1<cr><lf>Host:data.sparkfun.com<cr><lf>Connection:keep-alive<cr><lf>
^z
```

When I enter this command `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","data.sparkfun.com",80` I will get back **CONNECT OK**(TCP connection success) and just after that it will automatically close it **+TCPCLOSED:0**(TCP connection is closed by remote server). There is no time to enter the **AT+CIPSEND** command because the TCP connection is lost.

I tried to make my own nodejs server but still the same problem.

How to keep the connection alive until I can send data and then close the  connection with **AT+CIPCLOSE** command?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the solution is very simple.

The AT-Command

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
```

defines the PDP context and I guess the "internet" was just a generic value and you might have to replace it by the APN of your mobile network provider.